# Vue.js - Value of prop is changing but I never mutate it (and I don't want it to change)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a custom component, I have a prop **selectedUser** defined like this:

```
  props: ['selectedUser'],
```

I have a data prop like this:

```
   data() {
    return {
      user: this.selectedUser,
    };
  },
```

All the inputs in the component have the v-model set like this:

```
<input type="text" v-model="user.first_name" />
```

The custom component is a modal for adding a new user. If the user exits the modal w/o saving, I have this to reset it to a blank form:

```
resetUser() {
  alert('resetting form');
  this.user = this.selectedUser;
  alert(this.selectedUser.first_name);
},
```

I am expecting this.selectedUser to never change inside the component (and there is no code that causes this.selectedUser to change - the only mentions of this.selectedUser are shown in this post), however the value of this.selectedUser is changing when the user enters data in the input, and the last alert shows this to be the case.

I've tried setting the data property user via a computed property

```
  computed: {
    originalUser: function() {
      return this.selectedUser;
    },
  },
```

but of course you can't access computed properties in the data b/c of the vue component life cycle.

Can anyone explain why this.selectedUser is changing and/or suggest an alternate way to accomplish what I am trying to do (btw I want to reset it to the original value sent to the component b/c this will serve as and edit form as well as an add)?

Comment: Downvoter - why? If you're going to downvote please offer some suggested improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in Vue is a function that returns an object. In your case, the object returned has a `user` property that is a reference to the `prop` `selectedUser`. It is returning that `selectedUser` object, because `user` **is** `selectedUser`, the way you've set it up. When you modify the `data` item `user`, you're modifying the `prop` `selectedUser` because they are the same thing.

`v-model` will update the modeled property [every time the `input` event fires on its component][1]. You're updating that `data` property `user`, and by extension, the `prop` `selectedUser` every time you update a property of the object, in this case `first_name`

Probably you'll want to add a function to your `created` hook that sets `this.user` to `JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify(this.selectedUser))`. This will create a deep copy of that `selectedUser` object. Then, you can modify `this.user` as you see fit, then eventually call whatever function would update your user when you submit the form.

It'd look something like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    user: null
  }
},
props: ['selectedUser'],
created() {
  this.user = JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify(this.selectedUser))
}

  [1]: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model
```

Comment: As you and others pointed out the key here is that the `user: {}` syntax sets the value by reference (which I totally wasn't expecting but makes sense). I used your answer as my fix (in `data()` I used `user:{}` and in `created()` and `resetUser` I used `this.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedUser));`

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you do `user: this.selectedUser`, you are passing the object by reference: and when you `v-model="user.first_name"`, you are actually modifying the properties on the *original* object.